# WIQL: How to get the content of a field of a work item returned by a query

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have to obtain the value of a field in a single work item. The query only returns one work item, because in my where clause I specify exaclty which Work Item Id I want. It's sort of a `GetFieldByWorkItemId` kind of method:

```
public double GetOriginalEstimate(object id)
{
    WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(
        " SELECT [Original Estimate]" +
        " FROM WorkItems " +
        " WHERE [ID] = " + Convert.ToInt32(id)
        );

    return 0;
}
```

My two questions are:

1. How can I get a work item from the `WorkItemCollection` queryResults by Id
2. How can I get the value of the field that I'm interested in: `[Original Estimate]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than run a query, you can [retrieve a single work item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb140391.aspx) by it's ID:

```
WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem(int id)["Original Estimate"]
```

Comment: It's funny that there is no documentation about how to get a specific field from a work item! That worked, thanks.

Comment: It's actually described in the 'Remarks' section of the WorkItem class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.aspx There are also more examples in the TFS 2010 SDK: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk